# Is there a way to encrypt jenkins' config.xml?

Tags: jenkins

I'm a newbie in using Jenkins. I saw a tutorial that can bypass jenkins authentication by just changing the useSecurity from true to false in config.xml. By doing it, there will be no administrator or login attempt and anyone can access the "Manage Jenkins" and can configure it. Just wondering if there's a way to encrypt the config.xml and the jenkins can still recognize it, something like obfuscation?

Still, I can't find any solution.

Comment: If somebody has access to your jenkins filesystem - you already lost the game.

Comment: That's why you run Jenkins as it's own user  (and lock down the directories) and don't run jobs on the controller.